# How does a propfan work?

Tags: jet-engine, propfan

Could someone give me a simple working of a propfan? Also I've heard the 2 sets of blades in a propfan rotate in opposite directions. Is this true? And if so why?

Comment: You may explicit why ressources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propfan) can't help you.

Comment: Go to Wikipedia.  Search ‘turboprop’ and ‘turbofan’

Comment: The Wiki explanation were not simple, so that's why asked here :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple (source for all that follows is [Wikipedia - Propfan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propfan)):

You can think of the contemporary propfan as a turboprop that has two high rpm contra-rotating propellers or *fans* with six or more highly swept fan blades each. These fans are driven by a turbine engine through a reduction gear or a low-speed free turbine.

High rpm is used to reach higher speeds and altitudes than conventional propellers.

The contra-rotating fan arrangement is used to remove torque effect, and to enhance efficiency (note: some early versions had just one fan).

Fan blades are swept to keep drag minimal at high rpm (high blade airspeed).

*This description might very well be considered an oversimplification, but I guess this is what was asked for.*

Comment: Thx! The answer you gave is perfect!